# Can i put a PHP variable inside a PHP include?

Tags: php, include, include-path

I am unfamiliar with PHP; I suspect this is an easy question. Our web designer is out of town and I need to fix something on one of our web sites.

Basically, I want to be able to use a variable as part of a URL that is being called into a document.

the code:

```
<?php
$URL = p2 ; /* p1, p2, p3 or no can be used here */
?>

<?php include('includes/WL_cart_*URL*.php'); // calls the page I need?>
```

I just want to be able to type the correct page in `$URL` and that text be added to the url in the include. I tried putting the variable directly into the include but that didn’t work.

Comment: <?php include($url);?>

Comment: You can concatenate the var inside the include yes like this: `<?php include('includes/WL_cart_' . $URL . '.php');`

Comment: `include("includes/WL_cart_{$url}.php");`

Comment: Yes, you can, but remember that if not done properly - this can lead to serious security issue (so called file include exploit), read here for more details: http://blog.nearlyfreespeech.net/2009/11/05/a-php-include-exploit-explained/

Comment: this place is amazing, pop out to get a sandwich and so much help! 
ill just go try one o two of these things and get back to you all!
thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using double quotes like so:

```
<?php include("includes/WL_cart_{$URL}.php"); ?>
```

or if you insist on using single quotes, exiting them, and adding the `$URL` variable works, like so:

```
<?php include('includes/WL_cart_'.$URL.'.php'); ?>
```

Comment: ...and wrap the variable in quotes or your script will fail: `$URL = 'p2';`

Comment: Thank you.
i have used this, as sugested with he double quotes.
its working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

To add a variable inside a string you use `.`

`include('includes/WL_cart_' . $URL . '.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes " and a $ symbol to pull in your variable.

Also bear in mind that your first variable should also be "quoted":

```
<?php
    $URL = "p2" ; /* p1, p2, p3 or no can be used here */
?>

<?php include("includes/WL_cart_$URL.php"); // calls the page i need?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php include("includes/WL_cart_{$URL}.php"); ?>
```

But you need take care, for example, if $url = '../config/database.php.inc', will open the config file.

Comment: so, can this be exploited by evil people of the net??